# Warning: MySQL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, opencart

I have installed XAMPP on windows. Apache is running just fine on port 80 and 443, and mysql is also running on 3306. I am installing open cart 1.5 locally but on pre-installation its giving me error **"Warning: MySQL extension needs to be loaded for Open Cart to work!"** Mysql current settings is off.
Every thing looks fine , i have searched a lot but couldn't find any thing. What should i do?
My php version is PHP Version 5.5.33 and my open cart version is 1.5.4.

Comment: The 1.5 branch is a couple of years old - there's a chance it requires the obsolete `mysql_*` extension which doesn't exist if you're using PHP 7. Try OpenCart 2.2 instead.

Comment: Exactly this is the reason as em using PHP 7 so whats the solution actually i want to work in 1.5 to update my module?

Comment: Odds are - you can't; it sounds like it uses an obsolete PHP extension : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php - your only *real* option is to use a newer version of OpenCart.

Comment: FIne. just gone through this thread. and my conclusion is that i will need to  install xampp's old version which supports mysql. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'd not recommend downgrading to an old stack when you can just upgrade OpenCart tbh ... but it's your call.

Comment: actually em bound because i have a web running on 1.5x and cant update it as its not clients requirement. so i have to develop the upcoming module in 1.5x

Comment: @CD001 I have tried the same in PHP Version 5.5.33and still getting the same error now what can be the reason?

Answer (score 5):

Open file step_2.php under install folder comment the following line

```
 /*
if (!extension_loaded('mysql')) {
                        $this->error['warning'] = 'Warning: MySQL extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!';
                }*/
```

On step 3 select MysqlI. It will work on PHP 7

Note : I know this is not a clean way, But we can use this as hack for 1.5.x versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please open following folder:
xampp\php

and edit php.ini in text editor. search for extension=php_mysql.dll
and then remove ; form beginning of line. turn off the MySql server and turn on back. you will be good.