# Installing Opencart 1.5.x with PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, apache, opencart, opencart2.x

It's my first time using OpenCart. A strange issue appeared, when I've tried to install OpenCart version 1.5.4 on my computer. I've searched for an answer on forums, but community is not as large as WP's one.

[image]

I am using

```
Linux (Elementary OS - so Debian based), with 
LAMPP installed on my machine. 
PHP 7, 
10.1.13-MariaDB (innodb_version 5.6.28-76.1),
```

I don't have any problem installing OC 2.x.x on my computer, but installing 1.5.4 provides me with this message (image). I've tried to uncomment (and then restart lampp) `extension=php_mysql.dll` (php.ini), but that doesn't help.

What I am doing wrong? Keep in mind, I need to install this version, I've already tried 2.x (it works normally)!

Comment: You have `MariaDB` installed but are trying to connect to a `MySQL` database. I think that's your problem. I don't think you can use the MySQL database selection for a fork of MySQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36036465/warning-mysql-extension-needs-to-be-loaded-for-opencart-to-work/36318941). AlFra, please determine your loaded PHP modules from `phpinfo()` and add them inside your question please.

Comment: @Bram: isn't MariaDB meant to be a drop-in replacement for MySQL? This seems to be a database extension/driver problem, not the actual database. I'm wondering whether it is looking for the old MySQL extension that was removed in PHP 7 (though [the requirements](http://docs.opencart.com/requirements/) say that MySQLi is fine).

Comment: MariaDB shouldn't be the problem, it is still the mysql branch. I don't know. I don't have any problems installing 2.x.x versions, I don't have problem installing wordpress, joomla, etc. Requirements say it is fine indeed. it is weird

Comment: @halfer this guy has (probably) the same problem, but there was never a solution posted. He has php 5.5.33 installed on his computer, so even if I downgrade I could receive the same message.

Comment: "even if I downgrade I could receive the same message" - not necessarily. PHP5.5 has the `mysql` extension enabled by default, but on PHP7 it has been removed entirely. I wonder if OpenCart is insisting on this old deprecated module even though it claims to work with `mysqli`?

Comment: i am going to try. (& update you in a few)

Comment: @halfer this indeed worked. Please post your answer as an actual answer so I can checked it as accepted one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realised that the 1.5.x branch of this system is quite old. If you [take a look at the source for the installer file](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/1.5.6.4/upload/install/controller/step_2.php), it insists on the `mysql` extension. You could try hacking that, but my guess would be that it uses `mysql_` calls throughout, and the whole product won't work.

As soon as you [move to the 2.0.x tree](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/2.0.0.0/upload/install/controller/step_2.php), the number of permissible database extensions grows quite a bit. From this version, you can use any of these:

```
mysql, mysqli, pgsql, pdo
```

Note that `mysql` has been deprecated for quite a while, and in PHP 7 it was finally removed. You therefore are unlikely to be able to use OC 1.5 together with PHP 7.

Your possible solutions are:

- Downgrade to latest PHP5.x
- Upgrade OpenCart to 2.x

Comment: it is as you've said. I've downgraded, I don't get error message anymore. One question though: do you have any experience with migration from 1.5 to 2.0 (especially database). do you know where can I find answer? I've checked SO but everything (answers) seem so incomplete. I checked YT tutorials (i've found some fishy ones), there is also one repo on Github https://github.com/pekka2/OpenCart-Migration-Upgrade-Tool .could this be part of the solution?

Comment: None at all, I'm afraid - it doesn't enjoy [a spectacular reputation](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/250qjd/why_you_should_never_use_opencart_personal/) and I'd be wary of using it. Is there an importer in 2.0? Failing that you could set up a fresh instance of 2.x, create some products, and then examine the database format - maybe you can write your own migration script?

Comment: i will try to use that migration script from GitHub. I shall see if that does anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention it, my **OpenCart v.1.5.6.5**_rc work well with 
**PHP v.7.015** so far. I only had to upgrade the **OpenShop Extension** bypacked
**Sql-Buddy**, and the **eXtplorer** File Editor, to make everything work well again.

And all OpenCart v.1.5.6.0 - 1.5.6.5_rc have a Selection Box, to select
between 4 different DB Drivers, including **msqli**

And regarding OpenCart v.2.3.x, the latest Version **OC v.3.0** already exists on
Github.com, and soon, not many Dev's will care anymore anymore about those many unfinished and already outdated V.2.x versions, I assume.

But OC v.3.0 is an entirely new (TWIG-supported) Theme Design, technically at least. So, one will no longer be able, to use any of the so far existing v.1.x - v.2.x Themes and probably Extensions anymore. Just be aware of such, before possible destroying the still most reliable working OpenCart v.1.5.6.x Version on your Server.